# SQL inner join show only unique Drivers

Tags: sql

Learning, be kind.

Right now, this statement is showing the drivers and the vehicle id's they have used for these trips. how do I make this show only which drivers have used more than one vehicle rather than a list of vehicle ID and which driver used it?  (does that make sense?):

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.vehicleID, o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS Driver
FROM Operators AS o, Runs AS r, Schedules AS s JOIN Trips AS t
ON s.scheduleID = t.scheduleID 
WHERE r.BidDate >= '09/01/2004' AND r.BidDate <= '09/30/2004'
```

Comment: Is this Microsoft SQL Server? Or something else?

Comment: You should probably `INNER JOIN` all tables for "cleaner syntax", or as a bare minimum expand your `WHERE` clause to match relevant rows from different tables. After that, you could use `COUNT` to do that.

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Those table names don't make much sense to someone not familiar with the data.

Comment: You should under no circumstances use implilcit joins and it is far worse to then start mixing them with explicit joins. Learn SQL correctly and stop using syntax that was replaced more than 20 years ago with something better. Right now you have cross joins which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.vehicleID) AS Count, o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS Driver
FROM Operators AS o
JOIN Runs AS r ON o.ID = r.OperatorID
JOIN Schedules AS s ON r.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID
WHERE r.BidDate BETWEEN '09/01/2004' AND '09/30/2004' 
GROUP BY o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.vehicleID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS Driver, COUNT(s.vehicleID) NoOfVehicleUsed
FROM Operators AS o, Runs AS r, Schedules AS s JOIN Trips AS t
ON s.scheduleID = t.scheduleID 
WHERE r.BidDate >= '09/01/2004' AND r.BidDate <= '09/30/2004'
GROUP BY o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName
HAVING COUNT(s.vehicleID) > 1
```

Comment: If you're grouping by vehicleID, this should always return no rows.

Comment: @APH thanks for identifying that I took the question lightly :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's the purpose of each table , but assuming you have  table (`map_driver_To_vehicle`) with :

```
driverId , vehicleID
```

which represents that

- driverid 5 took vehicleId 1
- driverid 2 took vehicleId 5
- etc...

You can do :

```
select driverId , cnt=count(distinct vehicleID )
from map_driver_To_vehicle
group by driverid
having count(distinct vehicleID ) >1
```

nb : you said more then one vehicle. So I presume you mean different car and not used more then one - the same car.

Either way you can remove the distinct.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess not knowing the foreign key field names in your tables

```
SELECT
    o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS Driver,
    COUNT(s.vehicleID) AS VehicleCount
FROM
    Operators AS o
    JOIN Runs AS r ON o.operatorID = r.operatorID
    JOIN Schedules AS s ON r.runsID = s.runsID
WHERE 
    r.BidDate >= '09/01/2004'
    AND r.BidDate <= '09/30/2004'
GROUP BY 
    o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName
HAVING 
    COUNT(s.vehicleID) > 1
```